# VBA Replaces Space with %20

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, email-attachments

My file name contains spaces that are replaced with %20 when attaching the file to my e-mail.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="CLIENT NAME - OUR NAME- Statement of Account as of " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & ".xlsx"


       
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMessage As Object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMessage
    .To = " CLIENT EMAIL "
    .CC = " MY EMAIL "
    .Subject = "CLIENT NAME - OUR NAME - Statement of Account"
    .Body = "Dear Valued Client," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Attached is your weekly statement of account." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please let us know if you have any questions" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you," & vbNewLine & "Accounts Receivable Team"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
Set OutlookMessage = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
```

When the attachment is added to my email it shows "CLIENTNAME%20-%20OUR%20NAME%20-%20-Statement%20of%20Account%20as%20of%20Date%20.xlsx but the file itself saves correctly with spaces. When I attach the file manually it also saves correctly with spaces.

Comment: Is the folder on OneDrive ?

Comment: Please, try a testing sub with a single code line: `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: @CDP1802 The file is originally downloaded from a SharePoint Power BI. It saves to my download folder and when the VBA saves the file it saves it to my computer documents folder which I believe is still connected to my company's onedrive.

Comment: "email it shows "CLIENTNAME%20..." Where does it show %20's, in Outlook before it is sent or when it's received ?

Comment: @CDP1802 before it is sent. My macro formats and saves the spreadsheet, creates an email and attaches it to send.

Comment: What does the recipient see ?

Comment: @CDP1802 it shows the %20

Comment: @FaneDuru I can't get it to work

Comment: Couldn't you get to work `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName`?

Comment: any other suggestions @CDP1802

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is replace spaces in filename with underscores `_`

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you but my client is specific with the naming and wants spaces

Comment: @FaneDuru No I could not. Perhaps I was doing it wrong but nothing popped up when I ran that.

Comment: Nothing should pop up. You should use Ctrl + G to show Immediate Window. There the name will be returnrd. I thought you know that..

Comment: @FaneDuru C:\Users\username\OneDrive - Company\Documents\Client- Atrium - Statement of Account as of 03-27-23.xlsx

Comment: @FaneDuru It has to be because of SharePoint. I was having syncing issues today and when i ran the macro it did it correctly by pulling the local file instead of the SharePoint copy.  the Issue is i can't have the code say to save to my specific One Drive because others my use this macro

Answer (score 0):

When working with files from OneDrive/SharePoint, I've found that using the "DisplayName" parameter of the Attachments.Add expression will result in a filename that has spaces (e.g. not a URL encoded file name). In your example, just replace

```
ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

with

```
ActiveWorkbook.FullName, , , ActiveWorkbook.Name
```